# Cocos desktop app can not access to files on MacOS

Tags: xcode, macos, cocos2d-x, xcode9.1

I have an application with the following structure:

`./Data/test.txt`

`./TestMacOSApp`

So my TestMacOSApp opens `./Data/test.txt` and uses the content of `test.txt`. This app was working for a long time either on my MacBook or others MacBook. Recently I noticed that the app works on my MacBook fine,
but on others it crashes throwing "File is not found exception".

I create TestMacOSApp using XCode v9.1.
MacOS version is 10.12.6.

The App creation steps are `Archive->Export->ExportApp` (Without re-signing).

Does someone else have such an issue?
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: How is iOS involved here?  I'm confused.

Comment: Can you show the part of the code which opens the file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you open the file because you didn't provide the code which does this.

But I know that, when you export your app on other computers, it is important to calculate the real path with `fullPathForFilename`, instead of giving directly the path that you know. Like this:

```
auto fileUtils = FileUtils::getInstance();
string content = fileUtils->getStringFromFile(fileUtils->fullPathForFilename(filename));
```

Have you done this? If you have, and it doesn't work, your file is probably just not where you expect it to be, so please check again.